# Mysql: can't start mysqld "mysqld.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1"

Tags: mysql, linux

I have installed a third party framework `fate`, and `mysql` has been installed inside this framework, at the following path: `/data/projects/fate/common/mysql/mysql-8.0.28`.

I have copied `/data/projects/fate/common/mysql/mysql-8.0.28/conf/my.conf` to  `/etc/my.cnf` and the content is:

```
[mysqld]
port=3306
basedir=/data/projects/fate/common/mysql/mysql-8.0.28
datadir=/data/projects/fate/data/mysql
socket=/data/projects/fate/common/mysql/mysql-8.0.28/run/mysql.sock
max_connections=10000
max_connect_errors=10
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
mysqlx=0
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
[client]
port=3306
default-character-set=utf8
socket=/data/projects/fate/common/mysql/mysql-8.0.28/run/mysql.sock
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/data/projects/fate/common/mysql/mysql-8.0.28/logs/mysqld.log
pid-file=/data/projects/fate/common/mysql/mysql-8.0.28/run/mysqld.pid
```

but when I try to start mysqld with `systemctl start mysqld`, I get:

```
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

after `systemctl status mysqld.service`

```
● mysqld.service - LSB: start and stop MySQL
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-05-14 16:27:43 CST; 13s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 20483 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 14 16:27:41 vm-0-1-centos systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...
May 14 16:27:43 vm-0-1-centos mysqld[20483]: Starting MySQL..The server quit without updating PID file (/data/projects/fate/data/mysql/vm-0-1-centos.pid).[FAILED]
May 14 16:27:43 vm-0-1-centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 14 16:27:43 vm-0-1-centos systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL.
May 14 16:27:43 vm-0-1-centos systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
May 14 16:27:43 vm-0-1-centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

or when using `service mysqld start`, the problem is

```
Starting MySQL.The server quit without updating PID file (/data/projects/fate/data/mysql/vm-0-1-centos.pid).[FAILED]
```

I have tried a lot of solution from other questions, and I'm stuck and upset now.
I don't want to reinstall mysql again because I'm afraid that another mysql may affect the third party framework `fate` working.

Comment: Not really the place to ask that. But, anyway, MySQL 8 is a bit tricky, check carefully the log and ensure no deprecated option is in your my.cnf. Also, pid => accesses. Check that your mysql has access to where it is supposed to ; check apparmor etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking:

1. MySQL error log file
2. Privileges for MySQL catalogue

Comment: It seems the problem is directly in the config or accesses, I doubt the catalog to be involved here since the server didn't even start.

Comment: when I try to start mysqld,  `Starting MySQL.The server quit without updating PID file (/data/projects/fate/data/mysql/vm-0-1-centos.pid).[FAILED] 
`